# What are the options to load data from Datastage ETL tool into Google Cloud Storage and Google BigQuery

Tags: odbc, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, datastage

What are the options to load data using Datastage ETL tool into Google Cloud Storage and Google BigQuery?
I see that a third party provides 'Simba' which enable ODBC/JDBC connectors for querying data from BigQuery. But I am looking doing a direct load into Google Cloud Storage or Google BigQuery using DataStage ETL which is on premise.